# Паттерн "Модуль"

Tags: javascript, шаблоны-проектирования, модули

В книжке [«Паттерны для масштабируемых JavaScript-приложений»](http://largescalejs.ru/module-pattern) в разделе, где описывается паттерн "Модуль", написано, что модуль, в отличие от IIFE возвращает объект, а не функцию (2-й абзац).

Вопрос в следующем:
Что может вернуть JS-модуль, написанный согласно этому паттерну?
Разве я не могу вернуть, скажем, функцию-конструктор(класс)?
Правильно ли написано в книге об этом паттерне?

Answer (score 1):

> Вопрос в том, правильно ли написано в книге об этом паттерне (в
>   частности, во 2-м абзаце)?

Первым делом отвечу на это.

Как мне кажется, нет. Не совсем верно используются термины, что и привело вас в заблуждение. В частности, в этом 2-ом абзаце автор материала сравнивает Модуль как паттерн с IIFE (которые сами по себе не являются паттернами):

> Этот паттерн очень похож на немедленно-вызываемые функции (IIFE), за
>   тем исключением, что модуль вместо функции, возвращает объект.

Вообще, это довольно спорное утверждение, что IIFE не являются паттернами. Спецификацией языка они не определены как некая отдельная сущность, и свое название им действительно дало сообщество, из чего можно сделать вывод, что IIFE тоже являются паттерном. Но сейчас не об этом.

Сейчас я говорю о том, что автор статьи сравнивает 2 несравниваемые вещи. IIFE в привычном понимании - это самовызывающаяся функция, которая сама по себе не может ограничивать видимость свойств объекта. Посмотрите на код:

```
void function() {}();
```

Это - IIFE. Но где он здесь возвращает  функцию, как о нем говорит автор статьи?

А вот модуль:

```
var basketModule = (function() {
  var basket = []; // приватная переменная
    return { // методы доступные извне
        addItem: function(values) {
            basket.push(values);
        },
        getItemCount: function() {
            return basket.length;
        },
        getTotal: function() {
           var q = this.getItemCount(),p=0;
            while(q--){
                p+= basket[q].price; 
            }
            return p;
        }
    }
}());
```

И в результате исполнения этого кода переменная `basketModule` действительно будет содержать объект.

У меня есть 2 варианта того, почему автор привел такое некорректное сравнение:

1. IIFE - это, в рамках его статьи, название какого-то другого паттерна, а не тот IIFE, о котором мы с вами говорим.
2. Автор просто ошибся в формулировке мыслей.

Вообще, насколько я понимаю, автор хотел сравнить паттерн модуль с другим известным паттерном (сейчас не вспомню его название), который определяет конструктор объекта, а не сам объект в отдельности. Тут важно понимать, что само слово "Модуль" говорит о том, что полученный в результате объект уже является чем-то готовым, что можно, например, примешать (как модуль) к чему-нибудь.

А вот пример того известного паттерна, о котором говорил я:

```
let Constructor = (function() {
    let private = "Какое-нибудь приватной свойство (по сути, просто локальная переменная)";
    return function() {
        // к которой можно обратиться при помощи замыкания внутри конструктора. 
    }
}());
```

То есть в отличии от Модуля, здесь мы не получаем сразу какой-то готовый объект со скрытыми свойствами, а получаем *конструктор*, позволяющий генерировать объекты (тоже с приватными свойствами).

Вероятно, эти 2 вещи и приводил в сравнение автор вашей статьи.

### Подведу итог

Описанный в статье паттерн модуль подразумевает на выходе готовый объект, с которым уже можно как-то оперировать. Например, мы можете создать модуль Movable и при помощи `Object.assign()`, например, "примешать" его к какому-нибудь своему объекту, чтобы добавить вашему объекту функции, определенные этим модулем.

А IIFE, с которым его сравнивает автор, на самом деле не IIFE само по себе, а (как я предполагаю), совершенно другой паттерн, который при помощи все тех же (настоящих) IIFE позволяет реализовать своего рода приватные свойства на уровне конструктора (или прототипа объекта, см. комментарий).

Comment: Кстати, пример того паттерна, что я привел, можно также использовать при объявлении свойств прототипа, чтобы "создать приватные свойства" на уровне прототипа, а не на уровне самого объекта.